# PhoneGap: Deleted my APP, created again now AppStore does not accept it

Tags: android, cordova

Android AppStore says that the version code is newer and does not accept my app, any clue how to assign a version code manually?

I edited the config.xlm and on the "Widget" section, assign a Version:

versionCode= "420"

But Android keeps saying that the app version is newer than last. Seems that PhoneGap created a code somewhere-invisible and Android reads it there....

Too much inexperienced kids developing serious stuff....

Comment: just versionCode, if use "android:versionCode" PhoneGap finds an error

Answer (score 1):

Oops....After compiling 3 times in PhoneGap, it finally got the version code and Android AppStore accepted it...